# Download all files or with filter from remote url using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm unable to download files using wildcard. I have the following code which works partially:

```
$url = 'https://example.com/files'
$destPath = 'C:\myfiles'
$l = (Invoke-WebRequest –Uri $url).Links | ? href -like *exe
$l | select -Unique href | % { 
#get file name
$basename = $l | ? href -eq $_.href  | select -ExpandProperty innerHtml 
        "downloading file... $basename"
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url/$basename  -OutFile $destPath\$basename
}
```

This works fine for downloading files with the exe extension but what I really want is to download all files regardless of filename or extension. I have enabled directory browsing for this but I can't figure out how to download all the files. Even with -like I can't specify wildcard only. Seems to be for extensions only and one at a time at that.

Is it possible to just download whatever files are in that folder? One is web.config so it'd be nice to be able to specify a -notlike or -notmatch type of filter so that some files don't download.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm new to PS so can I get that in layman's terms? Could you please post an example? Also remember that the code above works if I want to download just *exe files but I want to download all kinds of files that might exist at that link, not just exe's.

Comment: I figured out what you meant but that made no difference nor do I see why it would because it's just another way of doing what I'm already doing. That means I'm still downloading all the files it finds except by the *exe filter. I don't want just exe's so ideally I'd just like to replace -like *exe with -like * but this gives me an error.

Comment: Instead of  ***|? href -like *exe***, then just use ***|? href*** then if you are just looking for when `href` contains a value.

Comment: I replaced it like u said and this kind of works because all files except for web.config get downloaded but I end up with this error:
downloading file... testfile.txt
downloading file... web.config
Invoke-WebRequest : Server Error
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

So it lists all the files as expected and downloads all files until it gets to web.config (which I don't really want anyway) but what to do with the error?

Comment: if you don't care about the error, then you need to suppress it somehow. That error is a non-terminating error. You will need to make it terminating, catch it, and do nothing with it--> `try { Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url/$basename  -OutFile $destPath\$basename -ErrorAction Stop } catch {  }`. It doesn't hurt anything to let it go as it only outputs to the console.

Comment: I was wondering why -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue wasn't working. I didn't know I had to catch it first. That works great! Thank you AdminOfThings. Only one problem, it's not downloading files with the extension .ps1 for some reason. It shows me "downloading file ... test.ps1" but it doesn't get downloaded.

Comment: If `-ErrorAction silentlycontinue` does not work, then the error was already terminating. So you can just leave off `-ErrorAction` all together.

Comment: So I tried that but .ps1 files still don't get downloaded. Even if I rename to some unknown extension like .zzz it doesn't download, but it does download if I rename it to .txt or .exe

Comment: Can anyone else chip in to resolve my problem? I need to be able to download all files from a URL but for some reason some files (such as .ps1) don't actually get downloaded even though it is found and says it'll download it

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue of some files not downloading by keeping my original code and just adding the code below to my site's web.config file in IIS:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="text/plain" /><!-- or application/octet-stream -->
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```